# How to use timeit module

Tags: python, time, timeit

How do I use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to compare the performance of my own functions such as "`insertion_sort`" and "`tim_sort`"?

Answer (score 323, accepted):

The way [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) works is to run setup code once and then make repeated calls to a series of statements.  So, if you want to test sorting, some care is required so that one pass at an in-place sort doesn't affect the next pass with already sorted data (that, of course, would make the [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) really shine because it performs best when the data already partially ordered).

Here is an example of how to set up a test for sorting:

```
>>> import timeit

>>> setup = '''
import random

random.seed('slartibartfast')
s = [random.random() for i in range(1000)]
timsort = list.sort
'''

>>> print(min(timeit.Timer('a=s[:]; timsort(a)', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
0.04485079200821929
```

Note that the series of statements makes a fresh copy of the unsorted data on every pass.

Also, note the timing technique of running the measurement suite seven times and keeping only the best time — this can really help reduce measurement distortions due to other processes running on your system.

Comment: Yes, it includes the list copy (which is very fast compared to the sort itself).   If you don't copy though, the first pass sorts the list and remaining passed don't have to do any work.  If you want to know the time just for the sort, then run the above with and without the ``timsort(a)`` and take the difference :-)

Comment: I'd recommend to repeat 7 times for each setup, and then average; rather than the other way round. This way, if each spike due to other processes has a good chance of being ignored entirely, rather than averaged out.

Comment: @max Use the min() rather than the average of the timings.  That is a recommendation from me, from Tim Peters, and from Guido van Rossum.  The fastest time represents the best an algorithm can perform when the caches are loaded and the system isn't busy with other tasks.  All the timings are noisy -- the fastest time is the least noisy.  It is easy to show that the fastest timings are the most reproducible and therefore the most useful when timing two different implementations.

Comment: You calculate an *average* (well, total, but it's equivalent) for 1000 inputs; then repeat 7 times, and take the *minimum*. You need the averaging over 1000 inputs because you want the average (not best-case) algorithm complexity. You need the minimum for precisely the reason you gave. I thought I can improve your approach by choosing one input, running the algorithm 7 times, taking the minimum; then repeating it for 1000  different inputs, and taking the average. What I didn't realize is that your `.repeat(7,1000)` already does this (by using the same seed)! So your solution is perfect IMO.

Comment: I can only add that how you allocate your budget of 7000 executions (e.g., `.repeat(7, 1000)` vs. `.repeat(2, 3500)` vs `.repeat(35, 200`) should depend on how the error due to system load compares to the error due to input variability. In the extreme case if your system is always under heavy load, and you see a long thin tail on the left of execution time distribution (when you catch it in a rare idle state), you might even find `.repeat(7000,1)` to be more useful than `.repeat(7,1000)` if you can't budget more than 7000 runs.

Comment: How about duplicating the array already in the setup, creating an iterator `it` over them, and then timing `'a=next(it); timsort(a)'`?

Comment: Why repeat one thousand executions 7 times? Is the idea not to run the setup once per execution? In which case surely the correct way to do it is repeat one execution 7000 times using `.repeat(7000, 1)`?

Comment: Some elaboration: creating a copy of the original parameters defined in `setup` in each iteration is only necessary if your function changes those parametes, like inplace sorting. E. g. for `sorted()` you wouldn't need the copy.
Of cause, one wants to test the performance of any function, with or without side effects. But if you avoid functions with side effects it should be safe to exclude the copy statement.
Now if you want to compare both types of functions and want really accurate measurements, you can subtract the duration of the copy mechanism from the tests where you applied it.

Comment: I just saw one of the above comments quoted about using the min time as it’s the least noisy. That advice is unsound. A low runtime can arise because of luck - for instance, that memory happened to arrive in a cache at just the right time. Anomalously low execution times are just that: anomalies. Repeating runs also has the effect of warming up the hardware and software caches, leading to likely unrealistic results. The best approach is to run an entire application end to end, and then forcibly flush any caches (including OS caches). Then report the median or mean and a confidence interval.

Answer (score 348):

If you want to use `timeit` in an interactive Python session, there are two convenient options:

1. Use the [IPython](http://ipython.org/) shell.  It features the convenient `%timeit` special function:

   ```
   In [1]: def f(x):
      ...:     return x*x
      ...: 

   In [2]: %timeit for x in range(100): f(x)
   100000 loops, best of 3: 20.3 us per loop
   ```
2. In a standard Python interpreter, you can access functions and other names you defined earlier during the interactive session by importing them from `__main__` in the setup statement:

   ```
   >>> def f(x):
   ...     return x * x 
   ... 
   >>> import timeit
   >>> timeit.repeat("for x in range(100): f(x)", "from __main__ import f",
                     number=100000)
   [2.0640320777893066, 2.0876040458679199, 2.0520210266113281]
   ```

Answer (score 194):

I'll let you in on a secret: the best way to use `timeit` is on the command line.

On the command line, `timeit` does proper statistical analysis: it tells you how long the shortest run took. This is good because *all* error in timing is positive. So the shortest time has the least error in it. There's no way to get negative error because a computer can't ever compute faster than it can compute!

So, the command-line interface:

```
%~> python -m timeit "1 + 2"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0468 usec per loop
```

That's quite simple, eh?

You can set stuff up:

```
%~> python -m timeit -s "x = range(10000)" "sum(x)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 543 usec per loop
```

which is useful, too!

If you want multiple lines, you can either use the shell's automatic continuation or use separate arguments:

```
%~> python -m timeit -s "x = range(10000)" -s "y = range(100)" "sum(x)" "min(y)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 554 usec per loop
```

That gives a setup of

```
x = range(1000)
y = range(100)
```

and times

```
sum(x)
min(y)
```

---

If you want to have longer scripts you might be tempted to move to `timeit` inside a Python script. I suggest avoiding that because the analysis and timing is simply better on the command line. Instead, I tend to make shell scripts:

```
 SETUP="

 ... # lots of stuff

 "

 echo Minmod arr1
 python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "Minmod(arr1)"

 echo pure_minmod arr1
 python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "pure_minmod(arr1)"

 echo better_minmod arr1
 python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "better_minmod(arr1)"

 ... etc
```

This can take a bit longer due to the multiple initialisations, but normally that's not a big deal.

---

But what if you *want* to use `timeit` inside your module?

Well, the simple way is to do:

```
def function(...):
    ...

timeit.Timer(function).timeit(number=NUMBER)
```

and that gives you cumulative (*not* minimum!) time to run that number of times.

To get a good analysis, use `.repeat` and take the minimum:

```
min(timeit.Timer(function).repeat(repeat=REPEATS, number=NUMBER))
```

You should normally combine this with `functools.partial` instead of `lambda: ...` to lower overhead. Thus you could have something like:

```
from functools import partial

def to_time(items):
    ...

test_items = [1, 2, 3] * 100
times = timeit.Timer(partial(to_time, test_items)).repeat(3, 1000)

# Divide by the number of repeats
time_taken = min(times) / 1000
```

---

You can also do:

```
timeit.timeit("...", setup="from __main__ import ...", number=NUMBER)
```

which would give you something closer to the *interface* from the command-line, but in a much less cool manner. The `"from __main__ import ..."` lets you use code from your main module inside the artificial environment created by `timeit`.

It's worth noting that this is a convenience wrapper for `Timer(...).timeit(...)` and so isn't particularly good at timing. I personally far prefer using `Timer(...).repeat(...)` as I've shown above.

---

#### Warnings

There are a few caveats with `timeit` that hold everywhere.

- Overhead is not accounted for. Say you want to time `x += 1`, to find out how long addition takes:

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit -s "x = 0" "x += 1"
  10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0476 usec per loop
  ```

  Well, it's *not* 0.0476 µs. You only know that it's *less* than that. All error is positive.

  So try and find *pure* overhead:

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit -s "x = 0" ""      
  100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.014 usec per loop
  ```

  That's a good **30%** overhead just from timing! This can massively skew relative timings. But you only really cared about the *adding* timings; the look-up timings for `x` also need to be included in overhead:

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit -s "x = 0" "x"
  100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0166 usec per loop
  ```

  The difference isn't much larger, but it's there.
- Mutating methods are dangerous.

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit -s "x = [0]*100000" "while x: x.pop()"
  10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0436 usec per loop
  ```

  But that's *completely wrong!* `x` is the empty list after the first iteration. You'll need to reinitialize:

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit "x = [0]*100000" "while x: x.pop()"
  100 loops, best of 3: 9.79 msec per loop
  ```

  But then you have lots of overhead. Account for that separately.

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit "x = [0]*100000"                   
  1000 loops, best of 3: 261 usec per loop
  ```

  Note that subtracting the overhead is reasonable here *only because* the overhead is a small-ish fraction of the time.

  For your example, it's worth noting that *both* Insertion Sort and Tim Sort have **completely unusual** timing behaviours for already-sorted lists. This means you will require a `random.shuffle` between sorts if you want to avoid wrecking your timings.

Answer (score 139):

If you want to compare two blocks of code / functions quickly you could do:

```
import timeit

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
func1()
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
func2()
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
```

Comment: Just use [`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) or `time.perf_counter_ns` instead

Answer (score 51):

I find the easiest way to use timeit is from the command line.

Given **test.py**:

```
def insertion_sort(): ...
def timsort(): ...
```

run `timeit` like this:

```
% python -m timeit -s 'import test' 'test.insertion_sort()'
% python -m timeit -s 'import test' 'test.timsort()'
```

Comment: Like it! Under a Windows command prompt, I had to use double quotes to avoid `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`. Yes, very late to the party.

Answer (score 35):

for me, this is the fastest way:

```
import timeit
def foo():
    print("here is my code to time...")


timeit.timeit(stmt=foo, number=1234567)
```

Answer (score 14):

```
# Генерация целых чисел

def gen_prime(x):
    multiples = []
    results = []
    for i in range(2, x+1):
        if i not in multiples:
            results.append(i)
            for j in range(i*i, x+1, i):
                multiples.append(j)

    return results


import timeit

# Засекаем время

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
gen_prime(3000)
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

# start_time = timeit.default_timer()
# gen_prime(1001)
# print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
```

Answer (score 14):

This works great:

```
  python -m timeit -c "$(cat file_name.py)"
```

Comment: What would be the Windows equivalent?

Comment: How do you pass parameters, if the script requires any?

Comment: @Shailen I found ```python -m timeit -s $(cat file_name.py)``` to work with PowerShell. With quotes around the ```$()```, PowerShell seems to output everything from file_name into one line which results in an error.

Answer (score 11):

simply pass your entire code as an argument of timeit:

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit(

"""   
limit = 10000
prime_list = [i for i in range(2, limit+1)]

for prime in prime_list:
    for elem in range(prime*2, max(prime_list)+1, prime):
        if elem in prime_list:
            prime_list.remove(elem)
"""   
, number=10))
```

Answer (score 5):

This has been answered a lot, but I just wanted to say that I find passing in the function directly much more ergonomic than passing in a string (as in all the other answers) or messing around with wrappers. For example,

```
import timeit

def my_sort(lst: list) -> list:
    do_something()

lst = [2, 3, 1]
timeit.timeit(lambda: my_sort(lst))
```

As a side note, ```timeit.repeat`` is also very useful, as it returns a list of times you can use to perform your own analysis. Also will recommend [perfplot](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/), which does much of this internally and produces a nice looking graph at the end.

Answer (score 4):

lets setup the same dictionary in each of the following and test the execution time.

The setup argument is basically setting up the dictionary

Number is to run the code 1000000 times. Not the setup but the stmt

When you run this you can see that index is way faster than get. You can run it multiple times to see.

The code basically tries to get the value of c in the dictionary.

```
import timeit

print('Getting value of C by index:', timeit.timeit(stmt="mydict['c']", setup="mydict={'a':5, 'b':6, 'c':7}", number=1000000))
print('Getting value of C by get:', timeit.timeit(stmt="mydict.get('c')", setup="mydict={'a':5, 'b':6, 'c':7}", number=1000000))
```

Here are my results, yours will differ.

by index: 0.20900007452246427

by get: 0.54841166886888

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 3):

```
import timeit


def oct(x):
   return x*x


timeit.Timer("for x in range(100): oct(x)", "gc.enable()").timeit()
```

Comment: What is `gc.enable()`?

Comment: Activation of the `Garbage Collection` that is usually deactivated during these timing runs.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in timeit module works best from the IPython command line.

To time functions from within a module:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import sys

def timefunc(func, *args, **kwargs):
    """Time a function. 

    args:
        iterations=3

    Usage example:
        timeit(myfunc, 1, b=2)
    """
    try:
        iterations = kwargs.pop('iterations')
    except KeyError:
        iterations = 3
    elapsed = sys.maxsize
    for _ in range(iterations):
        start = timer()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed = min(timer() - start, elapsed)
    print(('Best of {} {}(): {:.9f}'.format(iterations, func.__name__, elapsed)))
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of how to use Python REPL interpreter with function that accepts parameters.

```
>>> import timeit                                                                                         

>>> def naive_func(x):                                                                                    
...     a = 0                                                                                             
...     for i in range(a):                                                                                
...         a += i                                                                                        
...     return a                                                                                          

>>> def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):                                                                   
...     def wrapper():                                                                                    
...         return func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                  
...     return wrapper                                                                                    

>>> wrapped = wrapper(naive_func, 1_000)                                                                  

>>> timeit.timeit(wrapped, number=1_000_000)                                                              
0.4458435332577161
```

Comment: SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument. Ran it from REPL as well as separate file.

Comment: @ VladBezden, does `timeit.timeit(lambda: naive_func(x), number=1_000_000)` make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

You would create two functions and then run something similar to this.
Notice, you want to choose the same number of execution/run to compare apple to apple.
This was tested under Python 3.7.

[image]
Here is the code for ease of copying it

```
!/usr/local/bin/python3
import timeit

def fibonacci(n):
    """
    Returns the n-th Fibonacci number.
    """
    if(n == 0):
        result = 0
    elif(n == 1):
        result = 1
    else:
        result = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    t1 = timeit.Timer("fibonacci(13)", "from __main__ import fibonacci")
    print("fibonacci ran:",t1.timeit(number=1000), "milliseconds")
```