# Trying to use timeit.timeit

Tags: python, timeit

I'd like to measure the time of running for two codes, I tried looking up the python documentation for timeit, but I didn't really understand. 
Could someone explain in a more beginner-level vocabulary?

Comment: See also: [cProfile](http://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note:* Copied to [How to use timeit module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module/).

I'll let you in on a secret: the best way to use `timeit` is on the command line.

On the command line, `timeit` does proper statistical analysis: it tells you how long the shortest run took. This is good because *all* error in timing is positive. So the shortest time has the least error in it. There's no way to get negative error because a computer can't ever compute faster than it can compute!

So, the command-line interface:

```
%~> python -m timeit "1 + 2"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0468 usec per loop
```

That's quite simple, eh?

You can set stuff up:

```
%~> python -m timeit -s "x = range(10000)" "sum(x)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 543 usec per loop
```

which is useful, too!

If you want multiple lines, you can either use the shell's automatic continuation or use separate arguments:

```
%~> python -m timeit -s "x = range(10000)" -s "y = range(100)" "sum(x)" "min(y)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 554 usec per loop
```

That gives a setup of

```
x = range(1000)
y = range(100)
```

and times

```
sum(x)
min(y)
```

---

If you want to have longer scripts you might be tempted to move to `timeit` inside a Python script. I suggest avoiding that because the analysis and timing is simply better on the command line. Instead, I tend to make shell scripts:

```
 SETUP="

 ... # lots of stuff

 "

 echo Minmod arr1
 python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "Minmod(arr1)"

 echo pure_minmod arr1
 python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "pure_minmod(arr1)"

 echo better_minmod arr1
 python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "better_minmod(arr1)"

 ... etc
```

This can take a bit longer due to the multiple initialisations, but normally that's not a big deal.

---

But what if you *want* to use `timeit` inside your module?

Well, the simple way is to do:

```
def function(...):
    ...

timeit.Timer(function).timeit(number=NUMBER)
```

and that gives you cumulative (*not* minimum!) time to run that number of times.

To get a good analysis, use `.repeat` and take this min:

```
min(timeit.Timer(function).repeat(repeat=REPEATS, number=NUMBER))
```

You should normally combine this with `functools.partial` instead of `lambda: ...` to lower overhead. Thus you could have something like:

```
from functools import partial

def to_time(items):
    ...

test_items = [1, 2, 3] * 100
times = timeit.Timer(partial(to_time, test_items)).repeat(3, 1000)

# Divide by the number of repeats
time_taken = min(times) / 1000
```

---

You can also do:

```
timeit.timeit("...", setup="from __main__ import ...", number=NUMBER)
```

which would give you something closer to the *interface* from the command-line, but in a much less cool manner. The `"from __main__ import ..."` lets you use code from your main module inside the artificial environment created by `timeit`.

It's worth noting that this is a convenience wrapper for `Timer(...).timeit(...)` and so isn't particularly good at timing. I personally far prefer using `Timer` as I've shown above.

---

#### Warnings

There are a few caveats with `timeit` that hold everywhere.

- Overhead is not accounted for. Say you want to time `x += 1`, to find out how long addition takes:

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit -s "x = 0" "x += 1"
  10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0476 usec per loop
  ```

  Well, it's *not* 0.0476 µs. You only know that it's *less* than that. All error is positive.

  So try and find *pure* overhead:

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit -s "x = 0" ""      
  100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.014 usec per loop
  ```

  That's a good **30%** overhead just from timing! This can massively skew relative timings. But you only really cared about the *adding* timings; the look-up timings for `x` also need to be included in overhead:

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit -s "x = 0" "x"
  100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0166 usec per loop
  ```

  The difference isn't much larger, but it's there.
- Mutating methods are dangerous.

  ```
  python -m timeit -s "x = [0]*100000" "while x: x.pop()"
  10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0436 usec per loop
  ```

  But that's *completely wrong!* `x` is the empty list after the first iteration. You'll need to reinitialize:

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit "x = [0]*100000" "while x: x.pop()"
  100 loops, best of 3: 9.79 msec per loop
  ```

  But then you have lots of overhead. Account for that separately.

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit "x = [0]*100000"                   
  1000 loops, best of 3: 261 usec per loop
  ```

  Note that subtracting the overhead is reasonable here *only because* the overhead is much a small-ish fraction of the time.

Answer (score 2):

I find IPython's %timeit and %%timeit magic functions to be easier to use than timeit.timeit (particularly when using the ipython notebook). A couple of examples [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> "-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))
'0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23-24-25-26-27-28-29-30-31-32-33-34-35-36-37-38-39-40-41-42-43-44-45-46-47-48-49-50-51-52-53-54-55-56-57-58-59-60-61-62-63-64-65-66-67-68-69-70-71-72-73-74-75-76-77-78-79-80-81-82-83-84-85-86-87-88-89-90-91-92-93-94-95-96-97-98-99'
>>>
```

Suppose that's the command you'd like to run.
Import `timeit`. Make the command a string, add how many times you'd like to run it.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=100)
0.011214537887298093
```

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)
Is this doc really incomprehensible? I find it lucid clear.

Comment: what i mean is: I don't understand how to use it for my own type of funtion code