# Issues with using timeit in ipython

Tags: python, ipython, timeit

I was quickly trying to time 2 functions in ipython, `m1()` and  `m2()` doing the same task with 2 different implementation.

```
In [23]: %timeit for x in range(100): m1(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.6 us per loop

In [24]: %timeit for x in range(100): m2(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 us per loop
```

Result: the first implementation is almost 2x faster. So far, so good.

Out of curiousity, I changed the range of the `for` loop above, and now I am at a loss making sense of the output.

```
In [25]: %timeit for x in range(1): m2(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 us per loop

In [26]: %timeit for x in range(10): m2(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.8 us per loop

In [27]: %timeit for x in range(1000): m2(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop
```

What exactly is the for loop doing here? And why do the value of the number of loops decrease on increasing the range value?

PS: I was using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8220961/1860929) as the reference. Also, please edit the title to something better if it doesn't exactly convey my question.

Comment: Why are you using the `for` loop here? It is totally enough to do `%timeit m1(a)`! Otherwise you time the for loop as well.

Comment: Yup, I didn't realise initially what the for loop was doing :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timeit` is counting the execution time for the entire block.

So what you are seeing is:

- running `m2(a)` 1 time takes `1.29 us`
- running `m2(a)` 10 times takes `10.8 us`
- running `m2(a)` 1000 times takes `1.06 ms`

Which makes some sense, since `1.06ms = 1060 us`, roughly 1000x the baseline (and 10.8 us is roughly 10x the baseline)

As for the number of loops, timeit aims to run within a reasonable time:

```
$ python -mtimeit -h
...
If -n is not given, a suitable number of loops is calculated by trying
successive powers of 10 until the total time is at least 0.2 seconds.
```

Comment: That explains the output, but doesn't answer either of my questions - `What exactly is the for loop doing here?` and `why do the value of the number of loops decrease on increasing the range value?`

Comment: @ansh0l updated my response -- it's explained in the help for `timeit`

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. I wrote an answer for detailed explanation for my future self :)

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured it out what is happening, thanks to @Nirk's answer.

```
In [26]: %timeit for x in range(100): m2(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 us per loop
```

Here,

`%timeit` => ipython magic call

`for x in range(100): m2(a)` => the statement being executed. Based on the range value, time for execution increases/decreases for each run

`10000 loops` => Minimum number of loops that timeit will implicilty run, based on timeit modules constraint of minimum `0.2` s of total time

`best of 3: 108 us per loop` => average time taken by the best 3 loop run by timeit.

Assuming time for each run is same as average of best 3, time for each run = 108 us

minimum loops needed = `10^x`, where x is minimum positive integer satisfying `1.08 * (10^-4) * (10^x) > 2 * (10^-1)`

i.e, the minimum x for which `(10^x) > 1.85 * (10^3)` => `x = 4`

Hence minimum loops needed = 10^x = `10000 loops`.