# why does timeit module take longer time than the code produces output quickly in python?

Tags: python, function, timeit

here is the code to calculate fibonacci

```
import timeit
counter=0
def fibhelper(n):
  global counter
  counter+=1
  if n==0 :
     return 0
  elif n==1:
     return 1
  else:
     return fibhelper(n-1)+fibhelper(n-2)

print fibhelper(20)
print "Total function calls-- ",counter
t1=timeit.Timer('fibhelper(20)',"from __main__ import fibhelper")
y=t1.timeit()
print "normal method in secs: ",y
```

output is:

```
6765
Total function calls-- 21891
```

which comes out immediately, but it is still calculating `y`. why is this? when the `function` is evaluated quickly, why does `timeit` of that `function` takes longer?

Comment: Your output doesn't match your `print` statements. Why are you using a global `counter` here? Note that `timeit` runs your function 1 million times, not just once.

Comment: I pasted the correct code before, now it is corrected..

Comment: Your output still doesn't match your print statements.

Comment: I asked a similar question here, HTH http://stackoverflow.com/q/19473800/1860929

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default parameters of `timeit` include: `number=1000000`.

Quoting the documentation of `timeit`:

> ...  run its `timeit()` method with `number` executions.

Therefore, it is expected to take 1000000 times longer.