# Get execution time of Python script with C program

Tags: python, c, testing, execution-time

I have to get the execution time of a Python script with 100 different input values, so I wrote the following C program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int i;
    char command [200];

    for (i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
        sprintf(command, "time python program.py %d", i);
        system(command);
    };

    return 0;
};
```

With this program I can see the execution time of each execution, but I'd like to be able to catch it in a variable. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Perhaps what you're *really* looking for is [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).  See also [How to use timeit correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gettimeofday()` from `<sys/time.h>`  can be used in your case.

```
 double elapsedTime[100];
 for (i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {    
        sprintf(command, "python program.py %d", i);
        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
        system(command);
        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

        // compute and print the elapsed time in millisec
        elapsedTime[i] = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // sec to ms
        elapsedTime[i] += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms
    };
```

If possible, you can use some profiling tool which supports python.

Comment: If you're doing this, you don't need `time` in the command line.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes. Not needed.