# numpy array assignment using slicing

Tags: python, numpy

If b is a 2x2 np.ndarray and the following assignment is performed, what does numpy do in the background, i.e. does it convert the list[100, 100] **first** to a numpy array or does it **directly** use the list[100,100] to fill in the values in the first row of b:

```
 b[1,:] = [100,100]
```

Where in the documentation can I find more information about this?

Comment: `numpy` is open source, if you are interested in how something is *implemented* just look at the sources.

Comment: The answer is "it depends".  Look in `core/src/multiarray/sequence.c` in Numpy distribution (`array_assign_slice`: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/sequence.c#L91).  In your example, I think the code will not convert the list to an array, but depending on other cases, it may.

Comment: @goncalopp yes i am concerned about memory usage.

Comment: @Bakuriu I am well aware of that, but i am asking on stackoverflow on the off chance anyone has looked into this. Otherwise, any python related question can be answered by just looking at the source hence perhaps you think there is no need for a python tag here?

Comment: @AlokSinghal Thanks! Do you know of any cases/seen examples where that could be the case?

Comment: @methane I don't know -- you can look into the code but from a quick reading, it seems that a numpy array is created whenever destination dimensions are greater than the source dimensions: `a = numpy.empty((2,3)); a[:] = range(3)` for example.  I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

To evaluate the speed of execution, we will use the [timeit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-correctly) library.

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

setup = """
import numpy as np
tmp = np.empty(shape=(1, 100))
values = [i for i in xrange(100)]
"""

stmt1 = """tmp[0, :] = values"""
stmt2 = """
for i, val in enumerate(values):
    tmp[0, i] = val
"""

time1 = timeit.Timer(setup=setup, stmt=stmt1)
time2 = timeit.Timer(setup=setup, stmt=stmt2)

print "numpy way :", time1.timeit(number=100000)
print "Python way:", time2.timeit(number=100000)
```

You can test this and you will notice that numpy loops are twice faster :

```
- numpy way : 0.97758197784423828
- Python way: 2.1633858680725098
```

This is because there is a phase where the integers in `values` (which are unlimited integers) are converted into floats of 64 bits. In order to compare only the speed of the loops, the type conversion can be done preliminarily in the setup:

```
values = np.array([i for i in xrange(100)], dtype=np.float64)
```

Here is what I obtained :

```
numpy way : 0.131125926971
Python way: 2.64055013657
```

We notice that numpy loops are 20 times faster than Python loops.

You will find more information if you look for [vectorized computations in Python ...](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/python/9781449323592/4dot-numpy-basics-arrays-and-vectorized-computation/id2795683)

Answer (score -2):

`b[1,:] = [100,100]` is exactly the same as

```
b[1,0] = 100
b[1,1] = 100
```

It is however faster to execute as it uses compiled loops.
(The second one needs to do a conversion to the ndarray dtype before attributing the values).

Comment: Is this in the documentation somewhere? If so, could you please provide a link to where this is documented? Thanks

Comment: Yes, please let me know if it's somewhere in the documentation. What is a compiled loop?

Comment: Hello,
I am talking about the difference between interpreted language and compiled language. It is known that Python can be executed command by command, unlike C or Java that are compiled.
It is also known that numpy is a sort of interface that works with Python but runs as a compiled program. An example about loops performance is given in the answer that follows.