# Importing a local variable in a function into timeit

Tags: python, namespaces, timeit

I need to time the execution of a function across variable amounts of data.

```
def foo(raw_data):
   preprocessed_data = preprocess_data(raw_data)
   time = timeit.Timer('module.expensive_func(preprocessed_data)', 'import module').timeit()
```

However, `preprocessed_data` is not a global variable. It cannot be imported with `from __main__`. It is local to this subroutine.

How can i import `data` into the `timeit.Timer` environment?

Comment: Why not `time = timeit.Timer('module.expensive_func(data)', 'import module;data = generate_data()').timeit()`?  Also, if you need something more complicated you may actually want a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Works for this scenario, but what if you need the data outside the timer too?

Comment: Bingo. Sorry, @StevenRumbalski, this is indeed the case - the data is outside the timer too. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @EMiller:  `'import module;from __main__ import otherdata1, othedata2;data = generate_data()'` You can shove as much code as you want inside that bit of setup code.  If you have a lot of code for setup define setup as a multiline string before the `timeit` call.

Comment: It's more than just an answer to your question, but I feel I should advertise my guide to the `timeit` module: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24105845/1763356

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass it a callable to time, rather than a string. (Unfortunately, this introduces some extra function call overhead, so it's only viable when the thing to time swamps that overhead.)

```
time = timeit.timeit(lambda: module.expensive_func(data))
```

In Python 3.5 and up, you can also specify an explicit `globals` dictionary with a string statement to time:

```
time = timeit.timeit('module.expensive_func(data)',
                     globals={'module': module, 'data': data})
```

Comment: FWIW, using `functools.partial` removes about half of the function call overhead.

Comment: @Veedrac: I don't think that's actually removing the function call overhead, though. I think it's removing name lookup overhead that would occur in the real case.

Comment: @user2357112 True, but the point is that it's faster :P. Proper timings should time and subtract call overhead, so the smaller it is the less error it produces.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me inside `pdb` debugger and a class method. The solution that worked is to add the variables to `globals()`:

```
globals()['data'] = data
globals()['self'] = self
timeit.timeit(lambda: self.function(data))
```

> Note that the timing overhead is a little larger in this case because of the extra function calls. [[source]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer)