# Why time.time() gives 0.0?

Tags: python

I have a python program defined by a function `myFunc(m,n)`

Basically, the function contains two for loops.

```
def myFunc(m, n) : 
    for i in range(m) : 
        for j in range(n) : 
            # do it ...
    return
```

I would like to calculate the time elapsed for `m,n=20,20`

I do it like this:

```
start_time = time.time()
b = myFunc(m,n)
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print elapsed_time
```

The result is 0.0 almost always. Why?

Comment: 20 loops are too short. Try to make it artificially large.

Comment: It is rarely `0.0009` and almost always `0.0`.

Comment: LOL for the downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the `time.time` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time),

> even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second.

So if `myFunc` takes less than a second and you are using such an OS, then the difference between two calls of `time.time` could be 0.0.

You could use `timeit.default_timer` instead of `time.time`. `timeit.default_timer` will choose the best timer (`time.time`, `time.clock` or `time.perf_counter`) for your system.

Also note that [the timeit module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8220801/190597) offers more accurate ways to test the performance of code snippets.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Because `time.time() - time.time()` will be `0.0` when `myFunc` doesn't take very long.