# Don't understand how Timeit works. Need an explanation

Tags: python, timeit

I don't understand how I get `timeit` to work. I've made an example, where I want to calculate the difference in processing times. I would be eternally grateful if someone have the time to break it down for me.

Basse

```
def main():
    prod_nums = ['V475', 'F987', 'Q143', 'R688']

def search_fast(prod_nums):
    for item in prod_nums:
        if item == 'R688':
            return True
    return False

def search_slow(prod_nums):
    return_value = False
    for item in prod_nums:
        if item == 'R688': 
            return_value = True
    return return_value
```

Comment: I don't see much `timeit` in this question about `timeit`.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html) contains complete explanation with a bunch of examples. Do you have any specific problem?

Comment: I've read the documentation, but I struggle to understand how I can apply it to my example. I was wondering if someone could break it down for me. I'm in my starting phase of learning Python.

Comment: Simplest way to use `timeit` is in IPython: Just do `%timeit search_f(['V475', 'F987', 'Q143', 'R688'])`

Comment: If you are using interactive an session with IPython you can just time it as `%timeit search_f(prod_nums)` (same for `search_s`). If not, this question might have lots of duplicates (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module).

Comment: Or you can do it inside your file using following code `import timeit; print(timeit.timeit('search_f(prod_nums)', globals=globals()))`. The only trick is to pass `globals` parameter, so you can access your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass arguments to your function you might want to use `timeit.Timer`, but make your list global like this:

```
prod_nums = ['V475', 'F987', 'Q143', 'R688']
```

And then run this:

```
from timeit import Timer
t = Timer(lambda: search_fast(prod_nums))
print t.timeit() # In my case will print 0.336354970932
t = Timer(lambda: search_slow(prod_nums))
print t.timeit() # 0.374251127243
```

`timeit` is useful when you want to inspect small piece of code in your dev environment.

If your function looks like that:

```
def search_slow():
    prod_nums = ['V475', 'F987', 'Q143', 'R688']
    return_value = False
    for item in prod_nums:
        if item == 'R688':
            return_value = True
    return return_value
```

You can use `timeit.timeit`

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit(search_slow)
>>> 0.3833189010620117
```

This will not return any result thou, only the time it took. This is another scenario in which you can use decorator. 
Basically you can use `timeit` to tell you how much time does it take for a function to execute, much like `time sample_file.py` in your terminal.

Based on python docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html):
`This module provides a simple way to time small bits of Python code. It has both a Command-Line Interface as well as a callable one. It avoids a number of common traps for measuring execution times.`