# Python: the substitution of "%time"

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

As we know, we can use `"%time ..."` in the notebook of `Jupyter`. However, we could not use this line in `Spyder`. I have several lines used for reading video, doing image process and then writing a new video.

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from IPython.display import HTML

output = 'test_images/white.mp4' # output video
clip1 = VideoFileClip("test_images/solid.mp4") # video is readed by many clips
clip = clip1.fl_image(process_image) # process_image is a function for processing the image clips from a video
%time clip.write_videofile(output, audio=False)

HTML("""
<video width="960" height="540" controls>
  <source src="{0}">
</video>
""".format(output))
```

Hence, how can I do if I use `spyder (anaconda 3.0)`? Any substitution for `'%time'`?

Comment: `timeit` is a python module that you can run on your code

Comment: @cricket_007 you mean that "import timeit" Then "timeit.clip.write_videofile()"?

Comment: Not quite... https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: See here, even. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module