# Benchmarking of code in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

I was trying to benchmark code so I was trying this:

```
from timeit import *
from random import randint as ri
def linsearch(s,x):
   for i in range(len(s)):
       if s[i]==x:
          return

# Set up code
S = """     
    s = []
    for i in range(10):
       s.append(random.ri(0,10))
    x=s[5]
 """
# benchmark code
B="""    
  linsearch(s,x)
   """
p=10
m=100
t=min(Timer(B,S).repeat(10,100))
print("t:",t)
```

But this is not working. It is not recognizing random. I am using python 3.6. How should I correct my code?

Comment: Of course it isn't. You forgot to import it where it matters.

Comment: Also: `n//2` - what is `n` ?

Comment: alfasin, I changed the code.  Igancio, can you explain what do you mean ?

Comment: If you `import random.randint as ri`, shouldn't your code use `ri()` rather than `random.ri()`?

Comment: John, it is not working. It is showing `ri()` not defined.

Comment: Shouldn't the import statement be part of the setup?

Comment: Why it should be part of S ?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8220943/4996248 The `timeit` module doesn't know what `random` is. You need to provide the context for your code to run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use timeit module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module)

Comment: In this statement that of the accepted answer, of whom you provided link `>>> print min(timeit.Timer('a=s[:]; timsort(a)', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)) ` what is the meaning of 'a=s[:]; timsort(a)` ?

Answer (score 2):

timeit seems to run the code snippet in a separate interpreter environment, so you will have to import the things in the setup code.

```
from timeit import *
def linsearch(s,x):
   for i in range(len(s)):
       if s[i]==x:
          return

# Set up code
S = """
from __main__ import linsearch
from random import randint as ri
s = []
for i in range(10):
    s.append(ri(0,10))
x=s[5]
 """
# benchmark code
B="""
linsearch(s,x)
"""
p=10
m=100
t=min(Timer(B,S).repeat(10,100))
print("t:",t)
```