# simple CPython program and its performance measure

Tags: python, cpython

how make a simple cpython program from scratch and measure it performance gain with its respective python program..
example if I make a program of 10! in python and the in Cpython how would I know how much it improves the performance of computation.

Comment: python is cpython ... Do you mean cython?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at : [How to use timeit module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module)

simple code to test time taken for a function:

```
def time_taken(func):
    from time import time
    start = time()
    func()
    end = time()
    return (end - start)

def your_func():
    #your code or logic


# To test
time_taken(your_func)
```

Use this mechanism to test time taken in both situations.

Let's say CPython took c seconds & Python took p seconds, CPython is faster than Python by: (c - p) * 100 / p

If c is 2 secs & p is 1 sec. CPython is faster than Python by (2-1)*100/1 = 100%

However, the performance keeps changing depending on the code & problem statement.

Share the output. Goodluck!