# Is it possible to find index positions of certain rows in a big Dataframe (80000 rows, 6 columns) using iloc method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

My data frame has six columns of float data and around 80,000 rows. One of the column is "Current" and sometimes it is negative. I wanted to find index locations when the "Current" value is negative. My code is given below:

```
currnet_index = my_df[(my_df["Current"]<0)].index.tolist()
print(current_index[:5])
```

This gives output as I wanted:

```
[0, 124, 251, 381, 512]
```

This is fine. Is it possible to write this code using `iloc` method? I tried with following code and but it is giving error. I am wondering to know which of them is best and fastest method?

```
current_index = my_df.iloc[(my_df["Current"]<0)]
```

The output is:

```
NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation-how-are-they-different  iloc gives you rows based on the location given..it wont return indexes...also as the error says it expects integers whereas the condition is giving boolean values..to make sense add .index after the ()

Comment: @SarthakNegi, I just tried this `current_index = my_df.iloc[(my_df["Current"]<0).index]`. It gives error.

Comment: your objective was to get the indexes right ?...also can you post the error message because it works fine for me...

Comment: If the indices are not unique identifiers you can simply use `np.where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `iloc` you need to use a Boolean **array** rather than a Boolean *series*. For this, you can use [`pd.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html). Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Current': [1, 3, -4, 9, -3, 1, -2]})

res = df.iloc[df['Current'].lt(0).values].index

# Int64Index([2, 4, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Incidentally, `loc` works with either an array or a series.

Comment: Thanks. It did work. I am wondering how to find the execution time of these two methods? I mean, which is effective and best code to use? Please, let me.

Comment: @Msquare, You can use `timeit`, e.g. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module). I do not expect you to see a significant performance difference; you should first check whether this is truly the bottleneck in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following

```
my_df.ix[my_df['Current']<0].index.values
```

Comment: It gave output with a warning: `.ix is deprecated. Please use
.loc for label based indexing or .iloc for positional indexing`

Comment: In that case use .loc instead of .ix