# Python time the procedure by my own function

Tags: python, time, runtime, timeit

I defined a function here to calculate the time of procedure 'p' takes.

```
def timeit(p):
    a=time.clock()
    p
    b=time.clock()
    print(b-a)
```

Then I use  another function to test it.

```
d=pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randint(1,100,10000)})
d['s']=None
def f1():
    for i in range(10000):
        if d.iloc[i,0]<60:
            d.iloc[i,1]='under'
        elif d.iloc[i,0]<80:
            d.iloc[i,1]='ok'
        else:
            d.iloc[i,1]='best'
```

Use my timeit:

```
timeit(f1())         
5.140552730154013e-07
```

The result is absolutely wrong. Why? Is there any problem in my grammar?
The true time is:

```
a=time.clock()
f1()
b=time.clock()
b-a
Out[26]: 5.914697663515881
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeit(f1())` calls `f1` **before** passing its return value to `timeit`, so what you're actually measuring is just the overhead of calling `time.clock` twice.

You need to pass the function *itself* and call it in `timeit`, *between* the calls to `time.clock()`:

```
def timeit(p):
    a=time.clock()
    p()              # call it here
    b=time.clock()
    print(b-a)

timeit(f1)           # NOT here
```

If you need to pass arguments later on you can either use `*args / **kwargs` or 
 re-write `timeit` as a [decorator](https://medium.com/pythonhive/python-decorator-to-measure-the-execution-time-of-methods-fa04cb6bb36d).

```
def timeit(func, *args, **kwargs):
    a = time.clock()
    func(*args, **kwargs)
    b = time.clock()
    print(b - a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong because your code `f1()` does not actually get run between the two `clock()` commands.  `f1()` gets evaluated before  the call to `timeit` and not within the call. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module) for more info.