# Using timeit in interactive mode

Tags: python, ipython, timeit

How can I implement this ipython code in python?

```
[1]  %timeit sum(list(range(1000)))
```

Ps: I want to do it in a single line of code. I have tried several times but failed every time.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use timeit module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module)

Comment: `ipython` does some hidden stuff regarding the environment and problem namespace.  So it will be hard to implement something with the module that's a simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the time taken (in seconds):

```
from timeit import timeit
timeTaken = timeit(lambda: sum(list(range(1000))), number=100000)
```

You can look up the timeit documentation for more options.