# Get time execution. Compare list.pop(0) vs list().reverse(), list().pop()

Tags: python

I have a long list. I need to get the first element in the loop and remove it. So I'm trying to compare two functions that do it, but every time I'm getting different time execution.

```
from timeit import timeit
>>> def foo(l):
    start = timeit()
    while l:
        l.pop(0)
    end = timeit()
    return end - start

>>> def bar(l):
    start = timeit()
    l.reverse()
    while l:
        l.pop()
    end = timeit()
    return end - start

l = [i for i in range(100000)]
>>> for i in range(10):
    print(bar(v.copy()) - foo(v.copy()))


0.00021689999266527593
-0.015974199995980598
-0.0048112000222317874
0.0016583999822614715
-0.03471089998492971
-0.0077514999866252765
-0.0015070999943418428
0.0010934000019915402
-0.005327999999281019
0.000683299993397668
>>>
```

Am I doing everything right?

Comment: No, you seem to be confusing `timeit.timeit` with `time.time`. You should read the documentation of both to get an understanding of what they do and how to use them.

Comment: As I get it, the only difference is that eventually "timeit " is  more precisely

Comment: See also [How to use timeit module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct way to use `timeit` would be:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('import time; time.sleep(1)', number=10 )
10.008471012115479
>>>
```