# syntax in %time in Python using VS 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio-2019, timeit

in jupyter notebook, I can do

```
%time print 'hello world'
```

and it will print out wall time etc.

But I cannot do the same in Visual studio 2019, I am using python 3.8, it complains syntax error

ipython is there

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean "ipython is there"? Just because it is installed doesnt mean you can evaluate cell magic commands from a plain Python script.

Comment: First, `print 'hello world'` is invalid Python3 syntax. Second, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module

Comment: New in python, under my virtual environment, iPython is there.  So how can someone print out the wall time in VS 2019?  I know, it should be print('hello world')

Comment: Well, you can use [notebooks in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support), not sure of VS2019. Otherwise, what you are trying to do is just short-hand for the answer in linked post