# To check the time used by python to write your data inside a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, csv, time

I am trying to see how I can check the time taken by python to write the data inside a csv file.
Here is a sample code that I am trying to work:

```
import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
df_text.to_csv('D:\\DF.csv', index = False)
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
```

More specifically, How can I see the write time taken by df_text to fill in the data inside DF.csv? I believe this code (in 3rd) tells me the time taken to create the CSV file inside the directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use timeit module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module)

Comment: The code you have does this.  Does it not work for you?

Comment: Hi Sushanth, thanks for the suggestion, if i use timeit in my existing code it tells me how much time it takes by python to create this csv file. I need to see the time taken by df_text to fill the csv file.

Comment: Also note that you need EITHER the `r` prefix or the double slashes, not both: `r'D:\DF.csv'` or `'D:\\DF.csv'`

Comment: Hi Robert, this code only tells me the time taken to create the csv file in my directory. I want to see the time taken by df_text to fill all the values inside the csv file.

Comment: The time there includes both operations.  It takes no time at all to open a file, so you can assume that the bulk of your time is writing the values.

Comment: @AlexMAthew as said below, the time to open a file is probably insignificant enough that it won't even show in your result, especially if you are using seconds. And if the file is already created, it should just open it

Comment: @TimRoberts I added a snippet code, request you to please let me know if I am doing it right?

Comment: That's not going to tell you anything new.  You already know how long `df_text.to_csv` takes.  You did that in your first snippet.  `to_csv` creates AND FILLS the CSV file, and I"m not sure why you think there's more to it.

Comment: Ya, I got confused, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way is correct, another way to check average time taken by a function is to run it multiple times. Can be done using [Timeit Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module)

Comment: Hey Sarthak, this code only tells me the time taken to create the CSV file in my directory. I want to see the time taken by df_text to fill all the values inside the CSV file

Comment: Please include a snippet of code in the links you share in the future.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way.

@BrandonKauffman the link I have shared has a code snippet.

Comment: @SarthakAgarwal links can change, websites can go down. Use three tic marks ` to copy the important parts of your code