# Which code for getting a list of palindrome numbers is preferable?

Tags: python-3.x

You need to get a list with all palindrome numbers in the range from 100 to 1000. This problem can be solved in two ways:

1. Check the first and last digits of the number, and if they match, write them to the list.

```py
palindromes = [n for n in range(100, 1000) if n // 100 == n % 10]
print(palindromes)
```

2. Convert the number to a string and check it with its "inverted" copy.

```py
palindromes = [i for i in range(100, 1001) if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]]
print(palindromes)
```

**Question:** Which of these methods is preferable (interpreted faster or takes up less PC resources) and which one is better to use?

Comment: "interpreted faster or takes up less PC resources" - you can measure this using the built-in `timeit` library

Comment: Personally, I prefer the variable named 'n'. Besides, depending on how python the third is programmed, I'd say, nevertheless, that the integer version is likely faster and takes less ressources.

Comment: I suggest reading through this Q&A to see how to time these two list comprehensions yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module/ - as for "which one is better to use", that is a matter of opinion so it's not a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I recently started learning Python and didn't know about timeit. Tnanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Times along with another solution:

```
 67.6 μs  [n for n in range(100, 1000) if n // 100 == n % 10]
419.0 μs  [i for i in range(100, 1001) if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]]
 10.1 μs  [i*10 + i//10 for i in range(10, 100)]
```

"Resources" (memory) is minimal for all of them.

The `str` solution has the advantage of scaling most *easily*, i.e., you could for example change its range to `range(100, 1000001)` and it would find longer palindromes.

The non-filtering solution has the advantage of scaling *best*, i.e., for longer numbers the method would be even faster in comparison to the others.

My benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/NSsQwEL7nKb7L0mSttmFRpNCn2GMpskKqc0gaJuPBd/MZfKWapOIKO4fkm/l@4Iuf8r6G03PkbVt49RDyjgTk48oCdtFdRKkzRkwKeZopYFkZARTAl/DmtO37FvnpDWjJRNeVDeOY8SHDuWl/rVStdGu11ZqENZli3NE0DPd2/mc/2h53oK7L/01SDTJFPStV2JcrezJDzSjnVM7nfS8juZunoPeuOrUIH/7V8VjiDGqZP3FkCqKbw@ODXfD9ldDkilpwhHVPpkUy6ioz2/YD)):

```
from timeit import repeat

S = [
    '[n for n in range(100, 1000) if n // 100 == n % 10]',
    '[i for i in range(100, 1001) if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]]',
    '[i*10 + i//10 for i in range(10, 100)]',
]

for _ in range(3):
    for s in S:
        t = min(repeat(s, number=100)) / 100
        print('%5.1f μs ' % (t * 1e6), s)
    print()
```

Comment: Well, does that answer the question??

Comment: Maybe. Question is ambiguous. Even right away starts with a lie ("You need to").

Comment: "Question: which of these methods is preferable: <2 methods>" sounds pretty clear to me

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad Title: *"Which code for getting a list of palindrome numbers is preferable?"* sounds more general.

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad Plus if we only ever did what the OPs asked, we'd all be missing out on a lot of improvements just because the OPs unnecessarily restricted things.

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad Better now?

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot!