# How to efficiently get common items from two lists that may have duplicates?

Tags: python

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
my_list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The common items are:

```
c = ['a', 'b', 'a']
```

The code:

```
for e in my_list:
   if e in my_list_2:
      c.append(e)
      ...
```

If the my_list is long, this would be very inefficient. If I convert both lists into two sets, then use set's intersection() function to get the common items, I will lose the duplicates in my_list.

How to deal with this efficiently?

Comment: The situation you've shown actually runs in linear time relative to the size of the list, since hashtable lookup (for `my_dict`) is constant-time. I don't think you an get better than that.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy OK, I changed to this form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Answer to Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462202/4541045)

Answer (score 1):

`dict` is *already* a hashmap, so lookups are practically as efficient as a `set`, so you may not need to do any extra work collecting the values - if it wasn't, you could pack the values into a `set` to check before checking the `dict`

However, a large improvement may be to make a generator for the values, rather than creating a new intermediate list, to iterate over where you actually want the values

```py
def foo(src_dict, check_list):
    for value in check_list:
        if value in my_dict:
            yield value
```

With the edit, you may find you're better off packing all the inputs into a `set`

```py
def foo(src_list, check_list):
    hashmap = set(src_list)
    for value in check_list:
        if value in hashmap:
            yield value
```

If you know a lot about the inputs, you can do better, but that's an unusual case (for example if the lists are ordered you could [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect), or if you have a huge verifying list or very very few values to check against it you may find some efficiency in the ordering and if you make a `set`)

Comment: Can you see my updated question? I can convert the dict into a list or set first, then the question is how to get common items with duplicates?

Comment: Only one new list 'c' is created. Why do you think a new intermediate list created?

Comment: if you create a generator, you don't need to create `c` at all and can instead iterate over the result (as presumably is wanted later)! `for value in foo(src_dict, check_list): ...`

Comment: Hi, I still have to go rough each element in your 'check_list' variable. If this list is long, then it's an efficiency issue. Is there a way to avoid iterating through the. long list? If I convert this list into a set.then I lose the duplicates in the list.

Comment: @marlon this actually has a surprising number of questions associated with it and being very clear is your best chance of getting a good Answer! .. for example, the resulting order of elements will depend on which list is iterated over first if no other ordering happens .. and if the ordering and quantity is only taken from one list, making a `set()` of the other is likely a speedup .. please do prepare some more examples of what different inputs and outputs would look like if my Answer doesn't work for your case [`timeit` can help compare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24105845/4541045)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about time efficiency, but, personally speaking, list comprehension would always be more of interest to me:

```py
[x for x in my_list if x in my_list_2]
```

##### Output

```
['a', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: Can it be more efficient for two lists that I want to keep duplicates?

Comment: my_list_2 can be converted to a set, but still have to go through each element in the first list.

Comment: @marlon my_list_2 is actually a dictionary. So in this variable, there is no duplicated value.

Answer (score 0):

First, utilize the `set.intersection()` method to get the intersecting values in the list. Then, use a nested list comprehension to include the duplicates based on the original list's count on each value:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
my_list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

c = [x for x in set(my_list).intersection(set(my_list_2)) for _ in range(my_list.count(x))]
print(c)
```

The above may be slower than just

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
my_list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

c = []
for e in my_list:
   if e in my_list_2:
      c.append(e)
print(c)
```

But when the lists are significantly larger, the code block utilizing the `set.intersection()` method will be significantly more efficient *(faster)*.

Answer (score -1):

sorry for not reading the post carefully and now it is not possible to delete.. however, it is an attempt for solution.

```
c = lambda my_list, my_list_2: (my_list, my_list_2, list(set(my_list).intersection(set(my_list_2))))
print("(list_1,list_2,duplicate_items) -", c(my_list, my_list_2))
```

Output:

```
(list_1,list_2,duplicate_items) ->  (['a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'a'])
```

or can be

```
[i for i in my_list if i in my_list_2]
```

output:

```
['a', 'b', 'a']
```