# Inference time of yolov4 object detection model

Tags: tensorflow

I am running the yolov4 object detection model on raspberry pi 4B and jetson nano. I have to record the inference time. I am using 12 images for evaluation. how can I record the inference time of this model? Is there anything for calculating the inference time?

Comment: `time.time()` ?....

Comment: Consider using [timeit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module/48302720)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @MohammadSaeidAnwar you can use the time module at the starting of your inference before you start your inference to calculate the time.
For example

```
import time
begin = time.time()
time.sleep(5)
end = time.time()
print('Time taken:', round(end-begin, 2))
#output:Time taken: 5.01
```

Thankyou.